# Two components are overlapping each other after pushing to host

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

The navbar/header section of this project seems to be overlapping the Call To Action section after uploading it to host and then viewing it on my phone. This is confusing because on devtools when I switch to my iphone specific dimensions it is fine and all other listed device dimensions are responsive in devtools when working on the project on my computer. What could be causing this issue to happen after I push it to the host?

here is how it should look [image]

here is how the project looks on my phone
[image]

As you can see the top navbar is overlapping the CTA.

Here is the code for the app

```
   const App = () => (
  <div className='w-full overflow-hidden'>
    <div className='bg-cta-gradient z-[0] h-[450px] mobile-height-change'>
      <div className={`fix-bg-img flex-col h-[450px] mobile-height-change
        relative overflow-hidden ${styles.paddingX} ${styles.flexCenter}`}>
        {/* background image  */}
        <div className='background-img z-[0] absolute overflow-hidden'></div>
         {/* header section  */}
        <div className={`mt-5 margin-bottom absolute z-[2] ${styles.boxWidth}`}>
          <Navbar />
        </div>
        <div className={`z-[0] mt-5 cta-mobile-change ${styles.boxWidth}`}>
          <CTA />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

        {/* body sections  */}
    <div className={`${styles.flexStart} mobile-margin-change`}>
      <div className={`${styles.boxWidth}`}>
          <BodyTop />
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div className='w-full h-[650px] md:h-[350px]'>
          <BodyMiddle />
    </div>

    <div className={`${styles.flexStart}`}>
      <div className={`${styles.boxWidth}`}>
          <BodyBottom />
      </div>
    </div>
    
       {/* footer section  */}
    <div className='bg-footerBgColor sm:h-[720px] md:h-[350px] mt-10 rounded-tr-[80px]'>
      <Footer />
    </div>
    
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

Comment: Please include a minimal and reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i dont know how to do that since the issue only happens after the website is hosted. the project is fine before that.